# How to identify what capabilities are required for a command?

Tags: linux, docker, capabilities

When I run a command within a docker container, I see:

```
# ip netns exec 9ee961d90990 ifconfig
setting the network namespace "9ee961d90990" failed: Operation not permitted
```

I can launch my container with expanded capabilities directly (I have added the `net_admin` one) but is there any way to check what system capability is required in order to run this command?

It is possible to start the container with `--privileged` to do this and trample over everything security related associated with docker but I'd rather avoid doing this if at all possible. Doing this does allow the above command to succeed.

Answer (score 5):

According to the [setns(2) man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setns.2.html) you'll need `CAP_SYS_ADMIN` in order to join the target network namespace. But you may probably need additional capabilities because `setns()` is used with a file descriptor to `/run/netns/...`. You don't tell how you've created this network namespace, so I assume it has been created through `ip netns add ...`, so it's a bind-mounted network namespace pointing into [`nsfs`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/559723) (namespace filesystem) anyway.

Since `/run/netns/...` is usually root-territory, you probably need `CAP_DAC_OVERRIDE` or `CAP_DAC_READ_SEARCH` too, see also [capabilities(7) man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html). Maybe, also `CAP_SYS_PTRACE`, because access to many `/proc` inodes is further restricted by the ptrace capability.

Comment: CAP_SYS_ADMIN you meant!

Comment: Correct, thank you very much for spotting and reporting this! I've corrected it.