# What is the NSFS filesystem?

Tags: linux, filesystems, namespace, snap

The kernel contains a filesystem, nsfs. `snapd` creates a nsfs mount under `/run/snapd/ns/<snapname>.mnt` for each installed snap. `ls` shows it as a 0 byte file.

The kernel source code does not seem to contain any documentation or comments about it. The main implementation seems to be [here](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/fs/nsfs.c) and the [header file here](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/uapi/linux/nsfs.h).

From that, it seems to be namespace related.

A search of the repo does not even find Kconfig entries to enable or disable it...

What is the purpose of this filesystem and what is used for?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As described in the [kernel commit log](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=e149ed2b805fefdccf7ccdfc19eca22fdd4514ac) linked to by jiliagre above, the `nsfs` filesystem is a virtual filesystem making Linux-kernel [namespaces](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/namespaces.7.html) available. It is separate from the `/proc` "proc" filesystem, where some process directory entries reference inodes in the `nsfs` filesystem in order to show which namespaces a certain process (or thread) is currently using.

The `nsfs` doesn't get listed in `/proc/filesystems` (while `proc` does), so it cannot be explicitly mounted. `mount -t nsfs ./namespaces` fails with "unknown filesystem type". This is, as `nsfs` as it is tightly interwoven with the `proc` filesystem.

The filesystem type `nsfs` only becomes visible via `/proc/$PID/mountinfo` when [bind-mounting](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/198590/what-is-a-bind-mount) an existing(!) namespace filesystem link to another target. As Stephen Kitt rightly suggests above, this is to keep namespaces existing even if no process is using them anymore.

For example, create a new user namespace with a new network namespace, then bind-mount it, then exit: the namespace still exists, but `lsns` won't find it, since it's not listed in `/proc/$PID/ns` anymore, but exists as a (bind) mount point.

```bsh
# bind mount only needs an inode, not necessarily a directory ;)
touch mynetns
# create new network namespace, show its id and then bind-mount it, so it
# is kept existing after the unshare'd bash has terminated.
# output: net:[##########]
NS=$(sudo unshare -n bash -c "readlink /proc/self/ns/net && mount --bind /proc/self/ns/net mynetns") && echo $NS
# notice how lsns cannot see this namespace anymore: no match!
lsns -t net | grep ${NS:5:-1} || echo "lsns: no match for net:[${NS:5:-1}]"
# however, findmnt does locate it on the nsfs...
findmnt -t nsfs | grep ${NS:5:-1} || echo "no match for net:[${NS:5:-1}]"
# output: /home/.../mynetns nsfs[net:[##########]] nsfs rw
# let the namespace go...
echo "unbinding + releasing network namespace"
sudo umount mynetns
findmnt -t nsfs | grep ${NS:5:-1} || echo "findmnt: no match for net:[${NS:5:-1}]"
# clean up
rm mynetns
```

Output should be similar to this one:

```
net:[4026532992]
lsns: no match for net:[4026532992]
/home/.../mynetns nsfs[net:[4026532992]] nsfs   rw
unbinding + releasing network namespace
findmnt: no match for net:[4026532992]
```

Please note that it is not possible to create namespaces via the nsfs filesystem, only via the syscalls [clone()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clone.2.html) (`CLONE_NEW...`) and [unshare](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/unshare.2.html). The `nsfs` only reflects the current kernel status w.r.t. namespaces, but it cannot create or destroy them.

Namespaces automatically get destroyed whenever there isn't any reference to them left, no processes (so no `/proc/$PID/ns/...`) **AND** no bind-mounts either, as we've explored in the above example.

Answer (score 11):

That's the "Name Space File System", used by the [`setns`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ioctl_ns.2.html) system call and, as its source code shows, [Name Space related ioctl's](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ioctl_ns.2.html) (e.g. `NS_GET_USERNS`, `NS_GET_OWNER_UID`...)

`NSFS` pseudo-files entries used to be provided by the `/proc` file system until Linux 3.19. Here is the [commit of this change](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=e149ed2b805fefdccf7ccdfc19eca22fdd4514ac).

See Stephen Kitt's comment about a possible explanation about this files presence.

Comment: You’re welcome! Regarding the underlying question in the question, I suspect (but I’m not 100% sure) that the reason `snap` bind-mounts those files is so that the corresponding namespace will be kept even when it has no running process.

Comment: Other example `ip netns` commands mount net namespaces to keep  them up without process. Example of use: to have a bridge staying in its own namespace without any iptables/ebtables/nftables interaction from other namespaces (it can still have its own ebtables rules, its own vlan settings etc.). This bridge is then linked to other namespaces with veth pairs

Comment: This series of articles on what kernel namespaces are also seems relevant: https://lwn.net/Articles/531114/#series_index

Comment: just fyi: docker is using nsfs too on archlinux for a while now.